# Why use lists for navigation menus?

Tags: html

I wonder why everybody uses unordered lists when making menus? Items can be blocks with `inline-block` display property (for horizontal menus). Is there any reason for using `ul` and `li` tags for menus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you think about it a menu is essentially a list of links. So in a way it makes sense to do that. Another benefit of using a *structured and semantic* tag, such as `ol` or `ul` is that a screenreader would understand it better than using a generic tag such as `div` or `span` which only define a section of a page, but not its meaning.

However with html5 you would probably want to do it with:

```
<nav>
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Page 1</a>
  <a>Page 2</a>
  <a>Page 3</a>
</nav>
```

---

**Edit:** I found the following over at [**css-tricks.com**](https://css-tricks.com/wrapup-of-navigation-in-lists/):

> #### "Against" navigation in lists
>
> - At least one screen reader user prefers navigation without lists,
>     which was the origin of the original article.
> - Simpler markup. nav > a > is easier/less than nav > ul > li > a.
> - Divs and spans can be just as good, especially with ARIA roles
>
> ---
>
> #### "For" navigation in lists
>
> - Announcing the number of items in the list can be helpful
> - Benefit to structure in non-CSS browsers (Lynx screenshot)
> - Long standing pattern that hasn't proven widely to be a big problem
> - Lists are a "hook" for screen readers, (e.g. press L for lists) and display heirarchy well
> - Safety: nothing can be in lists but list items, not so for nav
>
> ---
>
> #### Draw
>
> - The extra markup can be helpful for styling. I'm calling this a draw because it's true but reaching. I could wrap every div on a
>     page in another div and that might be helpful someday for styling.
> - You can't use role=navigation on a  anyway ("Allowed role values are
>     directory, listbox, menu, menubar, tablist, toolbar, tree and
>     presentation."). I'm calling this a draw since in either case you
>     should wrap navigation in a .
> - The "verbosity" of screen readers is a choice. Lists are more verbose, but that can be adjusted.
> - VoiceOver treats exactly the same
> - The spec doesn't care either way.

<sub>**Remember that the above is only the opinion of the author of the article.**</sub>

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not compulsory to use lists for this purpose .
But when you are developing a dynamic website where items in your menu keeps on increasing and decreasing  this convention makes your work much more managable.

So it's a good programming practice.

Answer (score -2):

There is actually a W3Schools article on this exact topic. (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)

Their reasoning is the same as what I assume most people's is. A menu is literally a "list of links" so it makes sense from an abstract point of view to use a list of links.

Plus it makes it easier for you (or someone else) to find and understand this code later.